# How to replace comma with semicolon as delimiter in url

Tags: javascript, json

I am attempting to add a combination of products and quantities to the end of a url string. Each combination of product/quantity is separated by a semi-colon rather than a comma.

This is what I did: https://test.com?products=81:1,77:1,107:1

This is what I want: https://test.com?products=81:1;77:1;107:1

The below code is how I am building the prods array and the prods returned is what is added to the end of the url.

```
json.forEach(function (obj) { 
    prods.push(obj.product_id + ':' + obj.quantity); 
});

return prods;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return prods;
```

returns the toString of an array with comma separators.

Just change to

```
return prods.join(':');
```

Actually just do

```
return json.map(obj => `${obj.product_id}:${obj.quantity}`).join(';');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have below a snippet of code which creates a 'template URL' based on your criteria. The semicolon comes from using [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) which converts the array of product:quantity into a string joined by semicolons.

Note that I decided you could use a more general purpose approach because you do not provide us with the data structure of your JSON, so the snippet I created is agnostic to that and instead focuses on you leveraging the result to your liking.

```js
var makeProductUrl = (array) => {
  var products,
      templateUrl = 'http://test.com?products=';

  products = array.map((elem) => { 
      return `${elem.product_id}:${elem.quantity}`;
  }).join(';')

  return `${templateUrl}${products}`;
};

var someArray = [
    {
      product_id: 'A',
      quantity: 1
    },
    {
      product_id: 'A',
      quantity: 123
    },
    {
      product_id: 'A',
      quantity: 88
    },
    {
      product_id: 'D',
      quantity: 12
    },
  ],
  url = makeProductUrl(someArray);

alert(url);
```